# If column less than value replace other column values awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to replace multiple column values if a certain queried column is below a certain value.

Example file test:

```
cat test
OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf    
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 Chordata 88 Fish 20  Salmon 0 pink 0 
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

Basically, I'd like to make taxonomic names "NA" if the confidence values are below a certain value.

I have tried this:

```
cat test | awk ' $3<90 {$2="NA"}1'
OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf    
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 NA 88 Fish 20 Salmon 0 pink 0
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

Which changes the Phylum name (Phy column) for the 2nd row to NA because the Phy confidence column (column 3) was below 90.

What Id like to do is if the value in column 3 falls below 90, then I want to change additional columns to the right (lower taxonomic levels) to NA as well: e.g.

```
OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf    
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 NA 88 NA 20 NA 0 NA 0
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

I thought this would be pretty easy, but how to change multiple columns when the 1st condition is met?

Thanks for any help.

LP

Comment: `awk ' $3<90 {$2="NA"; $4=“NA”; $5=“NA”}1'` or, I believe (but haven’t tested) you can chain these like: `awk ' $3<90 {$2=$4=$6="NA"}1'`

Comment: Ah! That is great (simple). What if I wanted to change diff.  columns to different values based on meeting meeting that first criteria ($3<90)?

Comment: Use that first example. You can do as many things inside a block `{}`. You just separate each thing with a semicolon. Consider `awk $3<90{$2=“NA”; print “something”; $4=$5=“x”; a=$6; print a}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` that filters a row when `$3 < 90` and changes each non-numeric field to `NA`:

```sh
awk '$3 < 90 {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i+0 != $i) $i = "NA"} 1' file

OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 NA 88 NA 20 NA 0 NA 0
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

Comment: thanks! that is very useful. What about changing each non-numeric field to NA when  below 90, but after any numeric field? (i.e for OTU 1, column  4,6, and 8 would be changed to NA (because each below 90). I guess that would require an array looking at each preceding column value?  i.e. result for OTU 1 would be ```1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia NA Venerida NA Rangia NA ```

Comment: You can try `awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i+0 == $i && $i < 90) $(i-1) = "NA"} 1' file` but I suggest keeping one question per post and avoid adding requirements from comment section

Comment: Sorry, I was just curious. Apologies!

Comment: Not a problem, hope I answered your query.

Answer (score 0):

> how to change multiple columns

Assuming you know their position in advance it is easy - just use multiple `=`, let `file.txt` content be

```
OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf    
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 Chordata 88 Fish 20  Salmon 0 pink 0 
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

then

```
awk '$3<90 {$2=$4=$6=$8="NA"}1' file.txt
```

output

```
OTU Phy P.conf Class C.conf Ord ord.conf Spec S.conf    
1 Mollusca 90 Bivalvia 80 Venerida 80 Rangia 80
2 NA 88 NA 20 NA 0 NA 0
3 Cnidaria 100 Coral 78 fire 22 octo 12
```

Note that this is not limited to columns, but you might do this also with built-in variables, for example

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
```

does set both field separator (`FS`) and ouptut field separator (`OFS`) to be `,` and others variables for example

```
BEGIN{x=y=z=1}
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN{x=1;y=1;z=1}
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*